# Deserializing Object return empty object

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, deserialization, .net-5

I'm trying to read a file from a folder in my project and return the content as json.
This is my code:

```
string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);
return Ok(jsonObject);
```

This is the file content:

```
[{"grouping":"IS3","count":327.0,"population":12.0,"weight":31.0},
{"grouping":"ISO","count":31.0,"population":31.0,"weight":27.0}]
```

This is the response from postman:

```
[
    [
        [
            []
        ],
        [
            []
        ]
    ]
]
```

If I put a break point I can see that the jsonObject is filled correctly.

I forgot to say I made the file with another endpoint reading from a file excel.
The fields are not always the same, I made the object dinamicaly so I can't use a  class.

I'd like to return a json as content type, not a text.

Comment: How you are using PostMan?

Comment: Can you show us snapshot of postman api call? that might give us some idea

Comment: What is `jsonObject.GetType()`?

Comment: The json format you received is completely different that of what you deserializing.

Comment: provide some more code , this three line code working fine and give valid output.

Comment: @FedericoAlberti Why do you need to deserailize at all? Why don't you simple return the read text?

Comment: Did you try to deserialize to dynamic? ```var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(allText);```

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the correct file? Bacause the deserialization of the JSON you posted just works.

Answer (score 3):

You are using JSON.Net to deserialise and not providing a type. This means it gets deserialised into `JArray` and `JObject` types. Then you are using the default serialiser of ASP.NET Core which is `System.Text.Json`, and that doesn't know what to do with the JSON.Net types which is why you get all those nested arrays. Stick with one method of serialising. You have various options, here's a couple:

1. Use a proper class to deserialise and stick with `System.Text.Json`. This would be my preferred option.

   ```
   // Add these if missing:
   //using System.Text.Json;
   //using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

   public class MyThing
   {
       [JsonPropertyName("grouping")]
       public string Grouping { get; set; }
       [JsonPropertyName("count")]
       public double Count { get; set; }
       [JsonPropertyName("population")]
       public double Population { get; set; }
       [JsonPropertyName("weight")]
       public double Weight { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   And deserialise like this:

   ```
   var jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyThing>>(allText);
   return Ok(jsonObject);
   ```

   **Note:** If you cannot create a class because the JSON is dynamic, you could fall back to using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(allText)`
2. Send the JSON string back to the client manually

   ```
   return new JsonResult(jsonObject.ToString());
   ```

Comment: I can't make a class because the file changes each time i read it. I read the file excel, make the object dinamically and then write on the file.

Comment: Check the line where I added the comment about using `object`

Comment: I tryed but nothing changes sadly.

Comment: Sorry, I may have left in the JSON.Net code, try the updated code.

Comment: @DavidG in this way the endpoint will return a string, text/plain and not a JSON (application/json). This behaviour can cause issues to clients.

Comment: How can i return JSON (application/json)?

Comment: @Giox Fixed the second version to not do that. First version works fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to model the type and desrialize the JSON. No need to add any property annotations. This should work

```
public class MyObject
{

    public string Grouping { get; set; }

    public double Count { get; set; }

    public double Population { get; set; }

    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can,

```
// read file into a string and deserialize JSON to a type
MyObject object1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\alltext.json"));
return Ok(object1);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it's now using two different JSON libraries.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get that.. How is that. I just ran the code and looks like working.Just imported JSONConvert library

Comment: `return Ok(object1);` is using the default serialiser in ASP.NET MVC Core which is `System.Text.Json`, not Newtonsoft. See my answer.

Comment: MyObject changes each time I read the excel file with another endpoint. I don't have a static model for MyObject, I made it dinamically.

Comment: @FedericoAlberti I added a line to my answer to show what to do when your JSON is dynamic